# ReportViewer control in a webpart in SharePoint displays 401 for some reports

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2013, iis-8.5, reporting-services-2012

I am trying to solve an issue with the Report Viewer control displaying the message:

> The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.

rather than a report. This message is shown in the location where the report would be displayed. The Share Point parts of the page are displayed normally.

This occurs in a Report Viewer control on a SharePoint 2013 page.

Some other reports on other pages show up just fine. In Report Server, the browsing permissions on these reports are the same.

A testing environment with the same configuration is working correctly. I could not find any differences in the web.config on the web server and in the RSReportServer.config file on the report server.

I http traffic from my browser, using the Network tab in the IE developer tools and saw something remarkable. POST Requests from javascript to the report server control are like:

```
/Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd?OpType=SessionKeepAlive&ControlID=597f9e1be96e4291b847ce06da66940d
```

and receive a HTTP 500 status, whereas the response body is just two bytes:

> OK

The report that works correctly, issues similar requests, but just receives HTTP 200 status, also with OK as response body.

On my testing environment, thing are different, again. The report issues three requests to ReportViewerWebControl.axd. The first get a HTTP 401 status. The next request adds an Authentication header with an NTLM token. This also gets an 401 status. The third adds another NTLM value and gets a 200 status.

This looks like some challenge mechanism and I found an MSDN article [Error: The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized when you open a report in Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0](https://support.microsoft.com/nl-nl/help/2011887/error-the-request-failed-with-http-status-401-unauthorized-when-you-op) and tested with  added to my RSReportServer.config file. This did not help and this key is also absent in my testing environment.

I also enabled FailedRequest logging to get more insight in the Internal server error, return by the requests to ReportViewerWebControl.axd. This logging is very elaborate, but I could not find anything pointing to a cause of this error.

Under request summary it reads

```
188. view trace 
Warning         -MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS 
ModuleName      ManagedPipelineHandler 
Notification    EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER 
HttpStatus      500 
HttpReason      Internal Server Error 
HttpSubStatus   0 
ErrorCode       The operation completed successfully. (0x0) 
ConfigExceptionInfo
```

and under Authentication & Authorization

```
No. Event  
60. view trace  -AUTH_START AuthTypeSupported   MapCliCert 
61. view trace  -AUTH_END   
64. view trace  -AUTH_START AuthTypeSupported   Basic 
65. view trace  -AUTH_END 
68. view trace  -AUTH_START AuthTypeSupported   NT 
70. view trace  -AUTH_END 
91. view trace  -FILTER_AUTH_COMPLETE_START 
92. view trace  -FILTER_AUTH_COMPLETE_END
```

I do not understand what all of that means, but it is the

> ErrorCode The operation completed successfully.

looks like a contradiction.

Does anyone have suggestions on next steps to tackle this problem?